# 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered -but it is

Tags: ms-access, 64-bit, oledb, oledbconnection

Short and sweet:

- app works on x86 machine but not on x64 (tried on a 2008 Server and a Windows 8)
- Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 already installed (also have Microsoft Office 2007 Access Database Engine installed)
- MS Office not installed
- confirmed the existence of C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\ACEOLEDB.DLL

Code:

```
string conn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
OleDbConnection _connOle = new OleDbConnection(conn);
```

Any ideas what I should do to get this app to work on the x64 machines? Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the 32 bit 2007 and the 64 bit 2010? Because that is what you need.

Comment: Interesting. I realized that I was not setting the target platform to x86, so once I did that properly the error went away. But I will keep your answer in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two scenarios that could explain your issue:

1. Your C# project is set to target both 64-bit and 32-bit platforms and the 64-bit machine has only the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed. The reference fails because the program is running as 64-bit but the machine is missing

   C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL
2. Your C# project is set to target 32-bit platforms only (x86) and the 64-bit machine has only the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed. The reference fails because the program is running as 32-bit but the machine is missing

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\ACEOLEDB.DLL

Note that the installer for the 64-bit version of the Access Database Engine installs *just* the 64-bit version, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question has already been answered, here's what fixed things for me after spending many hours on the problem.

I used Process Monitor to find out what registry key was being looked up.
It was `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEBD.12.0`.

In my case this key was missing despite "Microsoft Access database engine 2010" being listed in Programs and Features.

In addition the file `ACEOLEDB.DLL` already existed in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE14\`.

Reinstalling "Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable" quit without indicating any error, but Windows Event Log indicated a problem, and looking at the install log file, it appears that there was some version mismatch ("Another version of this product is already installed"). 
So, I uninstalled "Microsoft Access database engine 2010" from "Program and Features", and then reinstalled it.  Now it installed ok.
This resulted in the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.ACE.OLEBD.12.0` being added, and my copy of `ACEOLDBD.DLL` being replaced with an earlier version (14.0.7011.1000 from 14.0.7159.5000).